# Reading results from glob into a python function

Tags: python, glob

I am trying to automate some plotting using python and fortran together. 
I am very close to getting it to work, but I'm having problems getting the result from a glob search to feed into my python function.

I have a .py script that says

```
    import glob
    run=glob.glob('JUN*.aijE*.nc')

    from plot_check import plot_check
    plot_check(run)
```

But I am getting this error

```
    plot_check(run)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "plot_check.py", line 7, in plot_check
     ncfile=Dataset(run,'r') 
    File "netCDF4.pyx", line 1328, in netCDF4.Dataset.__init__ (netCDF4.c:6336)
    RuntimeError: No such file or directory
```

I checked that the glob is doing its job and it is, but I think it's the format of my variable "run" that's screwing me up.

In python:

```
    >>run
    >>['JUN3103.aijE01Ccek0kA.nc']
    >>type(run)
    <type 'list'>
```

So my glob is finding the file name of the file I want to put into my function, but something isn't quite working when I try to input the variable "run" in to my function "plot_check".

I think it might be something to do with the format of my variable "run", but I'm not quite sure how to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`glob.glob` returns a list of all matching filenames.  If you know there's always going to be exactly one file, you can just grab the first element:

```
filenames = glob.glob('JUN*.aijE*.nc')
plot_check(filenames[0])
```

Or, if it might match more than one file, then iterate over the results:

```
filenames = glob.glob('JUN*.aijE*.nc')
for filename in filenames:
    plot_check(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `Dataset` expects to be passed a single string filename, rather than a list with one element?

Try using `run[0]` instead (though you may want to check to make sure your glob actually matches a file before you do that).